# for loop initializing a deck of cards

Tags: c++, for-loop, default-constructor

I'm very new to programming. I have an assignment that basically plays the card game War. Using class Card and class Deck I need to create a standard deck of 52 cards first.

```
class Deck{
    private:
        Card arrDeck[52];
        int cardsIn;
    public:
        Deck();
        Deck(Card arrCard[], int i){

        }

        Deck& shuffle();
        Card getCard(int index);


};
```

^This is my Deck class

```
class Card{
    private:
        char value;
        int mathValue;
        char suit;
        bool isDestroyed;
        int rank;
    public:
        Card(){}
        Card(char m_value, char m_suit);
        char getValue();
        char getSuit();
        bool getIsDestroyed();
        void setValue(char m_value);
        void setSuit(char m_suit);
        void setIsDestroyed(bool m_isDestroyed);

        int operator + (Card card);
        bool operator < (Card card);
        bool operator > (Card card);
        bool operator == (Card card);
        bool operator != (Card card);
        void operator ~ ();
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& COUT, Card const& card);
};
```

^This is my Card class.

```
 Deck::Deck(){
        const char charValue[13] = {'A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'J', 'Q', 'K'}; //0 = 10
        const char arrSuit[4] = {'H', 'S', 'D', 'C'};
        for (int j = 0; j < 52; ++j){
            for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i){
                for (int p = 0; p < 4; p++){
                    Card temp;
                    temp.setSuit(arrSuit[p]);
                    temp.setValue(charValue[i]);
                    arrDeck[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        cardsIn = 52;
    }
```

This is how I'm trying to initialize the deck of 52 cards. I know something is wrong in the for loops because all the cards in arrDeck[52] are all King of Clubs.

How can I get the deck to correctly contains all 52 normal playing cards?

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < 52; ++j)` does not make sense if you then index by suit and value. You should have a way of calculating `j` like `int j = i*p`, instead of an other loop. As an other note, for comparison operators you should use `const Card&`. Shouldn't make too much difference, but for some types your implementation will be considerably slower.

Comment: Fyi, you're initializing 52 *decks*, over and over, on the same array. The same card gets set to all 52 different possible cards, ending with the "deck" being filled with the *last* card in all slots. Lose the `j` loop and store your code by calculation (ex: `arrDeck[i*4+p]`). there are multiple formulae that will work.

Comment: You could also declare j as part of the outer loop and increment it in the inner one: `for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 13; ++i){ for (int p = 0; p < 4; p++, ++j){` or use a pointer to iterate through the array: `auto pos = arrDeck; for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i){ for (int p = 0; p < 4; p++, ++pos) { ... pos->setSuite(...); pos->setValue(...); ...}`

Comment: Why don't you just `std::shuffle` the cards?

Comment: Side note: Anyone who needs the *This is my Deck class* to tell, them that `class Deck{ ... };` defines the `Deck` class probably shouldn't be at Stack Overflow. They should be reading a good introductory book on the C++ language.

Comment: @user4581301 Sorry I just don't know where to go for these answers. Let me know if you know a website more beginner friendly. Our teacher recommended asking questions here

Comment: You don't need a `Deck` class.  A simple container will suffice:  `std::vector<Card>` or `std::list<Card>` are some containers that model a deck of cards.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help in the comments. The Deck initialization finally worked with this:

```
Deck::Deck(){
    const char charValue[13] = {'A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'J', 'Q', 'K'};
    const char arrSuit[4] = {'H', 'S', 'D', 'C'};
    int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i){
            for (int p = 0; p < 4; p++){
                Card temp(charValue[i], arrSuit[p]);
                arrDeck[j] = temp;
                ++j;
            }
        }
    
    cardsIn = 52;
}
```

I see that I was trying to use the `for (int j = 0; j <52; j++)` to just have a variable that increases but had a big brain fart on that the for loop wouldn't work and that it would reiterate 52 times. Thanks again for the help and sorry for the intro question.